# SQL DateDiff - return row when one date field is 2 months older than another date field

Tags: sql, date

Each row has a BookedMonth and a ReportingMonth. I want to return the rows where the ReportingMonth is 2 Months greater than the BookedMonth.

```
ReportingMonth      BookedMonth
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2015-11-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2015-12-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 00:00:00 2016-01-01 00:00:00

WHERE

DATEDIFF,BookedMonth,ReportingMonth,2
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select * from table where datediff(month, ReportingMonth, BookedMonth) > 2;
```

**EDIT**

Or better... se comments here below:

```
select * from table where ReportingMonth > dateadd(month, 2, BookedMonth);
```

Comment: Remember that DATEDIFF returns the number of times the boundary value changes, not necessarily the time span.  For instance DATEDIFF(MONTH,'20160131','20160201') = 1 even though the two dates are only 1 day apart.

Comment: Thank you. Both work as the date will always be the 1st of each month.